# Code efficiency check for hangman in Delphi

Tags: game, hangman, delphi

I recently coded a game of hangman and wanted to know,

A: Are there any places it could be more efficient?

B: Are there any things that are distinctly wrong with it, since I know people seem to say to avoid using `GOTO` and `SLEEP`?

C: Is there a way to have it generate words randomly or a database the code could access?

If you don't get any of the variables please let me know, although I have made an effort to match the name to the purpose. (Also if anyone has a better way to print the man, that would be appreciated too).

Since this still hasn't been answered i'm going to try direct responses to only shortening the `Gameplay`. Many thanks!

Code:

```
program Hangman;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Math;

var
  WordPlaceHolder: array [1 .. 10] of string;
  BoardStore, BoardPieces: array [1 .. 6] of string;
  Wordlist: TStringList;
  Check, Lives, Points, Counter, RandomNum: integer;
  GuessedWord, SelectedWord: string;

procedure PrintGameBoard;
begin
  Writeln('  |//======|');
  Writeln('  |/      \| ');
  Writeln('  |        ', BoardPieces[1]);
  Writeln('  |      ', BoardPieces[2], BoardPieces[3], BoardPieces[4]);
  Writeln('  |       ', BoardPieces[5], ' ', BoardPieces[6]);
  Writeln('  |');
  Writeln(' /|\');
  Writeln('/|||\');
  for Counter := 1 to length(SelectedWord) do
    write(WordPlaceHolder[Counter]);
  Writeln('');
end;

Procedure GamePlay;
Begin

  Writeln('Please guess a letter');
  GuessedWord := 'a';
  Writeln(SelectedWord);
  repeat
    readln(GuessedWord);
    GuessedWord := lowercase(GuessedWord);
  until ((GuessedWord[1] in ['a' .. 'z']) and (length(GuessedWord) = 1)) or
    (lowercase(GuessedWord) = SelectedWord);
  if GuessedWord = SelectedWord then
  begin
    Points := 100;
    exit;
  end;
  for Counter := 1 to length(SelectedWord) do
  begin
    if SelectedWord[Counter] = GuessedWord[1] then
    begin
      WordPlaceHolder[Counter] := ' ' + GuessedWord[1];
      Points := 1;
      Check := Check + 1;
    end;
  end;
  if Points = 0 then
  begin
    BoardPieces[Lives] := BoardStore[Lives];
    Lives := Lives + 1;
  end;
  Points := 0;
  if Check = length(SelectedWord) then
    Points := 100;
  if Lives = 7 then
    Points := 100;
  PrintGameBoard;
End;

begin
  RANDOMIZE;
  Wordlist := TStringList.Create;
  Wordlist.CommaText :=
    'amazing,supreme,ironic,whatever,guesses,obscene,quintuple,eliminate,random,headway,existing,interest,leaves,seasons,swell,hyper';
  Writeln('Hangman');
  Writeln('Gameboard');
  BoardStore[1] := 'O';
  BoardStore[2] := '/';
  BoardStore[3] := '( )';
  BoardStore[4] := '\';
  BoardStore[5] := '/';
  BoardStore[6] := '\';
  Lives := 1;
  PrintGameBoard;
  RandomNum := randomrange(0, 16);
  SelectedWord := Wordlist[RandomNum];
  Writeln('');
  for Counter := 1 to 10 do
    WordPlaceHolder[Counter] := ' _ ';
  for Counter := 1 to length(SelectedWord) do
    write(WordPlaceHolder[Counter]);
  Writeln('');
  repeat
    GamePlay;
  until Points = 100;
  if Lives = 7 then
  begin
    Writeln('');
    Writeln('The word was: ', SelectedWord);
    Writeln('You lose, R.I.P.');
  end;
  if (Points = 100) and (Lives <> 7) then
  begin
    Writeln('');
    Writeln('Well done you win!');
  end;
  readln;

end.
```

Comment: Also avoid global variables, but use procedure/function parameters instead. Use `TArray<string>` instead of `array [1 .. 10] of string;`, that will make a lot of things easier and more flexible for changing laterz. Besides that we won't give you answers to add code you didn't implement yet, this is _off-topic_ here.